# How to prevent users to view unwanted data from my app by using just routes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to prevent fetching data using routes from an user?i have used app.post and app.get.But by using my app.get routes any one can view my data.How to stop it.

```
app.get('/fetchCategoryTopicSubTopic', fav_dbmodule.fetchCategoryTopicSubTopic);
```

Comment: Are you not using sessions or tokens?

Comment: m using session but when the user logins he can view any data through routes but he has been not authorized to view others data.But as he logouts the session ends and he cant view any data.

Comment: So then just check the data in the user's session before letting him view others' data? Do you already have role-based or other system of permissions for users?

Comment: Sessions give you authentication, you also need authorization middleware. Like somebody had suggested, maybe store user authorization level in the session and stop these requests in a middleware before the rute is git?

Comment: @mscdex: yes i have used that permission